# Time complexity for nested loops?

Tags: time-complexity

a)

```
sum = 0;
for(i=1;i<2*n;i++)
 for(j=1;j<i*i;j++)
  for(k=1;k<j;k++)
   if (j % i == 1)
   sum++;
```

b)

```
sum = 0;
for(i=1;i<2*n;i++)
 for(j=1;j<i*i;j++)
  for(k=1;k<j;k++)
   if (j % i)
   sum++;
```

I chanced the above two pseudo code above while looking for algorithm analysis questions to practice on. The answers for the above two snippets are O(n<sup>4</sup>) and O(n<sup>5</sup>) respectively.

Note that the running time corresponds here to the number of times the operation
sum++ is executed.

How is it that the time complexity for the above two algorithms different by an order of `n` when the only difference is the `if` loop testing for equality to `1`? How would I go about counting the O(n) complexity for such a question?

Comment: are you sure about the answers or are you askingif they are correct?

Comment: The answers are given on this paper online, I am not sure if they are right: http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~mouhoubm/=postscript/=c3620/solmidtW06.pdf

Comment: Why doesn't calculating a modulo (`j % i`) take time?

Comment: Also - (code review) misleading indentation. I think `sum++` should be indented more than the `if` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algorithm A**

Let's call `f(n)` the number of operations aggregated at the level of the outer loop, `g(n)` that for the first inner loop, `h(n)` for the most inner loop.

We can see that

- `f(n) = sum(i=1; i < 2n; g(i))`
- `g(i) = sum(j=1, j < i*i; h(j))`
- `h(j) = sum(k=1; k < j; 1 if j%i = 1, else 0)`

How many times `j%i = 1` while `j` varies from 1 to `i*i`? Exactly `i` times for the following values of `j`:

```
j = 0.i + 1
j = 1.i + 1
j = 2.i + 1
...
j = (i-1)*i + 1
```

So:

```
h(j) = sum(k=1; k < j; 1 if `j%i = 1`, else 0)
     = i

=> g(i) = sum(j=1, j < i*i; h(j))
        = sum(j=1, j < i*i; i)
        = i*i * i = i^3

=> f(n) = sum(i=1; i < 2n; g(i))
        = sum(i=1; i < 2n; i^3)
        <= sum(i=1; i < 2n; 16.n^3)   // Here just cap every i^3 with (2n)^3
        <= 32.n^4

=> f(n) = O(n^4)
```

**Algorithm B**
(With the same naming conventions as algorithm A)

How many times do we have `j%i` casting to `true`? Every time `j%i` is different from 0. And how many times does this happen? We need to remove the occurrences for which `j` is a multiple of `i`, which are `i`, `2.i`, ... `(i-1).i`, over the range of integers 1 to `i*i`, which has `i*i` numbers. This quantity is `i*i - (i-1) = i^2 - i + 1`.

As a result,

```
h(j) = sum(k=1; k < j; 1 if j%i = 1, else 0)
     = i^2 - i + 1
     = i^2 // dropping the terms i and 1 which are dominated by i^2 as i -> +Inf. 

=> g(i) = sum(j=1, j < i*i; h(j))
        = sum(j=1, j < i*i; i^2)
        = i*i * i^2
        = i^4

=> f(n) = sum(i=1; i < 2n; g(i))
        = sum(i=1; i < 2n; i^4)
        <= sum(i=1; i < 2n; 32.n^4)   // Here just cap every i^4 with (2n)^4
        <= 64.n^5

=> f(n) = O(n^5)
```

**Bottom line**

The difference of complexities between algorithms A and B comes from the fact that:

- You have `i` values of `j` for which `i%j = 1`
- You have `i^2 - i + 1` values of `j` for which `i%j <> 0`

Comment: wont `if`condition run equal number of times in both cases? what has it to take with `if`computing to `true` or `false`, it would be computed equal number of times in both. Plz help me with this.

Comment: @NamanKheterpal, yes, you are right, the condition will be evaluated in both cases - here the discrimination comes from the exercise's requirements which asked *specifically for the number of times the operation `sum++` is executed*. If we disregarded this condition, the complexity would be the same (`O(n^5)` for both (A) and (B)).